# Any solution for accepting a reply as an answer for a faith-based question?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer

I believe a lot of question will remain without any accepted answer because Islam is not like mathematics and is more based on faith, so each reply can be answer according to the reader faith or none of them!

What's the solution for such cases? Is it required to have an accepted answer for each question?

Comment: See also: http://meta.islam.stackexchange.com/questions/117/who-is-allowed-to-pick-best-answer

Comment: accpeting an answer is not required, there is proof: https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/167

Comment: and there is proof: https://islam.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer : "  that user has the option to "accept" an answer "

Answer (score 2):

This is not an issue restricted to this site. Technical sites face similar issues. One practice used on some sites is that after the answers are posted, someone (possibility OP) writes a CW answer with links to the other answers and brief (one-line) explanation of each and the answer acts as a reference to other answers.

---

As a side note, I think it is useful to remind that these Q&A site are similar to Wikipedia in content to some extent. A good Wikipedia article doesn't take sides but explains various perspectives with an impartial tone and without endorsing any of those viewpoints, contains useful information about what the topic and gives verifiable references for those information. ([Wikipedia:Neutral point of view](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia%3aNeutral_point_of_view).)

This site is not a place to debate, argue, or promote a particular viewpoint. If the OP wants answers from a particular viewpoint it should be made explicit in the question.

An accepted answer doesn't mean that answer is correct or endorsed or the other answers are incorrect, it means it is the answer that the OP found most useful/helpful.