# When should i accept my own answer when I know it is opinion based?

Tags: discussion

In order to create a well structured and detailed answer, I asked a separate question and answered it, then I refereed back to that answer in the previous answer.

Now, the separate question I asked was a controversial question with different of opinions, see it [here](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/39935/15201). I focused on one point of view in my [answer](https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/39936/15201) - the minority view. I also mentioned that the other point of view is the majority view, so I didn't really exclude that. What this means is that my answer, while it focuses on one point of view, it mentions both views.

**Question:** When should i accept my own answer (to my own question) when I know it is opinion based?

---

*I understand that it might differ depending on question and answer. But I am looking for some guide lines.*

In the question and answer I mentioned above, *I felt that I wanted to accept my own answer*, especially because I think it mentions both views and it is more detailed than the other answer which - although it is more up-voted - it is only trying to provide counter arguments (which ain't related to the question) and seems not to answer the question good enough. And this is after I edited it in order to make it fit in more ([see history](https://islam.stackexchange.com/revisions/39951/1)).

Comment: [Is it okay to have a 0% accept rate on this site?](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/167)

Comment: @qdinar thanks, that post is releted to my last point "I thought it might be statistically better".

Comment: If the answer has a positive score, the statistics consider the question "answered"; afaik it makes no difference if it's *accepted* as well.

Comment: @goldPseudo Thanks, that's good to know! *I removed that phrase now.*

Comment: [Meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) describes the mechanics of accepting your own answer: *There is no reputation awarded and the answer does not float to the top of the list.*  So the community can up-vote a better answer above a self-accepted answer anyway.

Comment: @RebeccaJ.Stones I see, thanks! I also thought the accepted answer maybe would have some psychological effects on the readers, i.e "the accepted answer" is "the right answer", especially if the votes would be  balanced, while the view in the answers can be biased.

Answer (score 1):

Is it important?

The point is stackexchange is a community based plattform. So no matter if you chose your own answer (because you might find it the most helpful) or not the community (at least a working/active one) may or should chose the best answer via the voting system.

So i don't see any difference nor importance whether you should chose your answer or not, or when you are allowed to chose it, as at least with the time the most helpful or best answer will get the highest voting rate (some kind of application of the law of large numbers I guess, probability theory was never my best topic!).

Comment: Thanks for your opinion! And 3id mobarak =)

Comment: عيد مبارك وتقبل الله منا ومنكم الصيام و القيام وصالح الاعمال